# Rust docs with declarative macros

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have two macros that build the same struct. `a!` matches the field name using a generic identifier, the `b!` matches the specific field name.

In VS Code, though, only `a!` let's the documentation comments work (i.e., hover over `name` inside the macro call and see the doc comment.

**How can I get `b!` to also show the documentation comments on hover?**

```rust
struct Hello {
    /// Name docs
    name: String
}

macro_rules! a {
    ($name:ident: $value:expr) => {
        Hello { $name: $value }
    };
}

macro_rules! b {
    (name: $expr:expr) => {
        Hello { name: $expr }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let hello_alice = a!(name: String::from("Alice"));
    let hello_bob = b!(name: String::from("Bob"));
}
```

[image]

I'm guessing the issue comes from the fact that in `b!`'s definition, Rust doesn't know that `name` refers to an identifier, and that the `name` in the matcher is the same `name` as the output.

Comment: I don't think you can because `name` is a literal part of the macro's syntax.

Comment: Hmm… anyway to instead match to "a specific identifier" and not just some random literal?

Comment: That honestly doesn't seem very useful, so I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: You can just type out the plain identifier like `(name: $value:expr)`. But in general, rust-analyzer isn't good at providing functionality inside function-like macros of any kind, so it's best to use them sparingly.

Comment: For the question itself, you should describe your requirements, because right now the best answer is to just use struct literal syntax instead of a macro. Macros are never the only solution. If that doesn't work for you, let us know why.